# -[_NSZeroData JMbase64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

When using `JumioCore.framework` I get this error when try to call a method which is in a extension:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSZeroData JMbase64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd709fa3aa0'
```

Example call that cause the exception:

```
NSData *data = [NSData data];
NSString *answer = [data JMbase64EncodedString];
```

why is this happening? What am I missing?
This is the Jumio webpage: https://www.jumio.com/implementation-guides/fastfill-netverify-mobile-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this answer is very simple but it was hard to find because `JumioSDK` doesn't explain that in its guide to install the SDK.

What you need to avoid those errors is include certain frameworks after start working. This is the list of the frameworks to be added:

- libz
- libiconv
- libc++
- MobileCoreServices
- Accelerate
- System configuration

also remember to add `-ObjC` in `another linker flags`

Let me know if someone have some problem.